# Dead temporary tables left behind

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have two temp tables in my production database, that just seem to be stuck

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_SYS_TABLES WHERE NAME LIKE '%#sql%';
+----------+--------------------+------+--------+-------+-------------+------------+---------------+------------+
| TABLE_ID | NAME               | FLAG | N_COLS | SPACE | FILE_FORMAT | ROW_FORMAT | ZIP_PAGE_SIZE | SPACE_TYPE |
+----------+--------------------+------+--------+-------+-------------+------------+---------------+------------+
|     4820 | mydb/#sql-1_4a84   |   33 |      7 |  4059 | Barracuda   | Dynamic    |             0 | Single     |
|     4586 | mydb/#sql-1_df2    |   33 |      7 |  3825 | Barracuda   | Dynamic    |             0 | Single     |
+----------+--------------------+------+--------+-------+-------------+------------+---------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

I am pretty sure they are dead. They have been there for days. I have a problem creating a foreign key constraint. I get

```
Can't create table `mydb`.`#sql-1_1888` (errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update")
```

This has happened to me before, where it was just a duplicate key name. Here this does not seem to be the case. I would like to drop the two temp tables, but how can I see what is in them?

Answer (score 1):

You can see the stored information of the tables using a `SELECT`:

```
USE mydb
SELECT * FROM sql-1_4a84
SELECT * FROM sql-1_df2
```

You can use [`DROP TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/drop-table.html) to remove the tables:

```
USE mydb
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS sql-1_4a84, sql-1_df2
```